# ASP Option Explicit - Paypal Express Checkout trouble

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am facing a big trouble when integrating PayPal Express Checkout in classic ASP.

The code provided by PayPal at the "[PayPal Integration Wizard](http://integrationwizard.x.com/ecpaypal/code.php)" works perfectly when run without `Option Explicit`.

When I put into my coding pages and call to the functions provided, I am facing big trouble: My existing pages all use `Option Explicit`.

This results in me having to manually declare all variables in the PayPal functions.

The sample PayPal functions consist of many array/list/object/index for setting up the name/value pairs necessary to call the PayPal site. It is totally not easy for me to change it over to all correct declaration, since I am not ASP expert and project deadline is tight.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be possible to mix "`Option Explicit`"-code with non-"`Option Explicit`"-code via the `Execute` statement.

Here's a small test I just made with VBScript (which applies to classic ASP as well):

```
''#vb1.vbs (i.e. "your code")
Option Explicit

Dim fso, vb2, txt
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vb2 = fso.OpenTextFile("vb2.vbs", 1)
txt = vb2.ReadAll

MsgBox txt    ''# Message 1
Execute txt

MsgBox foo    ''# Message 2
```

and

```
''# vb2.vbs (i.e. "their code")
j = 100

Function foo
  k = 100
  foo = j + k
End Function
```

Results in:

```
Message 1: (equal to the contents of vb2.vbs)
Message 2: 200
```

I have no idea if this is the best way to do it, but currently I can think of no better way. Give it a try.

Beware of namespace clashes through global variables or function names in "their code".

Comment: The downside is that ASP will cache parsed/tokenised and otherwise "compiled" ASP pages.  Whereas any code passed to Execute needs to be parsed and "compiled" each time the page is called.

Comment: The namespace collision risk can be mitigated by place most of your own code in a class thereby significantly reducing the set of identifiers you code creates at the global level.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: +1 for both of your comments, your're right. On the other hand - I think the parsing/compiling business takes negligible time, as it happens in-thread. The Script engine doing the request is already loaded, and the PayPal code will be trivial enough to be availibe within milliseconds. Nothing I would worry about.